# What is preventing me from using App Service logs?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

In the App Service Logs page , I do not have a option to do web server logging to storage. Instead , I see this error below. I don't want to rebuild the app service if I can avoid it. Any Tips?

[image]

Comment: Well, is the web app in the stopped state or not?

Comment: The web app occasionally is pending restart. but I see this error even when the app is running.